# Routes chunks are bundling external scripts in every chunk

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, code-splitting, webpack-externals

In my webpack I've used **externals** which has React, React Dom, Redux etc.

Now when I implement my Route Chunking, every chunk which is generated re-bundles the external scripts again, so eventually my bundle size is very huge.

How can I avoid my individual chunks not to re-bundle the external scripts and use them from externals.

**EDIT**

Using https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/ I can see that all my chunks are bundling common libs - which are are actually supposed to come from `externals` in webpack.

**EDIT 2**

***webpack file***

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

  entry: ['./src/containers/AppContainer', './src/index'],

  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: 'public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[id].chunk.[chunkhash].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },

  target: 'web',

  externals: {
    antd: 'antd',
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    'react-router': 'react-router',
    redux: 'redux',
    'react-redux': 'react-redux',
    immutable: 'immutable',
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias:{
      constants: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/constants'),
      actions: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/actions'),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles'),
      utils: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils')
    }
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      comments: false
    })
  ]

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          // Ignore local .babelrc files
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            ['es2015', { modules: false }],
            'react'
          ],
          plugins: [
            'react-html-attrs',
            'transform-class-properties',
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'transform-object-rest-spread',
            [
              'import', {
                libraryName: 'antd'
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
         ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?less$/i,
        exclude:'/node_modules/',
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot\?iefix$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000
        }
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          configFile: './eslint/.eslintrc',
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Routes file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

export default (
  <Route path='/base/'
    getComponent={ (location, callback) => {
      require.ensure([], function (require) {
        callback(null, require('./containers/AppContainer').default);
      });
    } }>

    <Route path='/route1'
      getComponent={ (location, callback) => {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          callback(null,
            require('./containter1')
            .default);
        });
      } }
    />

    <Route path='/route2'
      getComponent={ (location, callback) => {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          callback(null,
            require('./container2')
            .default);
        });
      } }
    />

    <Route path='/route3'
      getComponent={ (location, callback) => {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          callback(null,
            require('./container3')
            .default);
        });
      } }
    />
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: Are you actually importing those libraries in your separated routes/chunks? `import React from 'react'`. Using externals removes the need of importing the libraries

Comment: Yes I'm. In all my chunks I'm using `import React from 'react'`. Also my externals in webpack is already having react etc.... So my bundle should technically not include React at all in the chunks.... Any idea?

Comment: @Ematipico If I don't include the libs in chunks, it throws a compilation error

Comment: So, if you use externals, doing `import React from 'react'` is **not needed**. So probably there's something wrong with your webpack configuration? Can you share the code please?

Comment: @Ematipico `import React from 'react'` must be there? otherwise how will it resolve the React.Component?

I tried removing it but its giving compilation error during webpack build.

Comment: That's why I asked to check the configuration. The externals option is meant for this kind of scenarios. You don't need to import React because webpack will resolve the missing library safely, but you have to tell it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your externals section like this:

```
externals: {
    React: require.resolve('react'),
    'window.React': require.resolve('react'),
    ReactDOM: require.resolve('react-dom'),
    'window.ReactDOM': require.resolve('react-dom')
}
```

Also, remove `import React from 'react'` from your code. Just use `React`.

EDIT

Apologies, I edited my answer. Just realised my mistake. I changed the code. The key inside your  externals will be the name of the global variable. Usually it's also safer to put it inside the window object

Comment: Didn't work.... also when I remove `import React from 'react'` it gives error that React is not defined as my components are using `extends React.Component`

Comment: This is what I get on browser console `ReferenceError: React is not defined`

Comment: I can't understand why it's not working. You import your library before importing your bundle? I refer to your `index.html`

Comment: Yes ofcourse, the libs are loaded before including the bundle.

Comment: And you can actually see React object inside your developer tool console?